# How do I access transcluded content in the controller of my AngularJS component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a component with multiple transclusion slots, something like this:

```
  angular.module('myApp').component('myComponent', {
    controller: myComponentCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    transclude : {
      transclude1: '?transcludeOne',
      transclude2: '?transcludeTwo',
    },
    bindings: {
      // bindings here
    }
  });

  myComponentCtrl.$inject = ['$element', '$timeout', '$transclude',];

  function myComponentCtrl($element, $timeout, $transclude) {
    var vm = this,

    $transclude(function(clone, scope, futureParent, slot) {
       console.log('$transclude was called');
       console.log('clone:', clone);
       console.log('scope:', scope);
       console.log('futureParent:', futureParent);
       console.log('slot:', slot);
       // I want to know the content of the transclusion slot

    });

  }
```

If I run this, the console reads:

```
$transclude was called
clone: w.fn.init []
scope: b {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: .......
futureParent: undefined
slot: undefined
```

What I want is to get the content of the transclusion slot, so if my component is used like this:

```
<my-component>
  <transclude-one><span>This is transclude one</span></transclude-one>
  <transclude-two><span>This is transclude two</span></transclude-two>
</my-component>
```

I want my controller to know the content of the first slot, in this case `<span>This is transcluded slot one</span>`.
I tried to use the $transclude function for this, but I can't find a way and the documentation isn't very clear on this.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-

The docs mention parameters

> function([scope], cloneLinkingFn, futureParentElement, slotName):

but the 3rd and 4th parameter are always empty. Can anyone tell me how to use the $transclude function, and if I can achieve what I want?